# Load Resources for other Language

Tags: c#, resources, load, translation

I have an application, which works with Resources for translation. This is working great.
Now, I have a special requirement. For this, I have to load the resource-dll for another language (for example, the application starts and works with English, then I have to also to load the German-translations) and look into it for a translation.

Is there an easy-way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load the resourcemanager and If you need the resources for an specific language you will need to ask for them using the specific culture, using:

```
GetObject(String, CultureInfo)
```

You can create the culture that you need using:

```
new CultureInfo(string name)
```

Or

```
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(string name)
```

Or

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(string name)
```

The name is the culture name: "en" English, "de" German... You can see a full list on the following link: [cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Resources;
using System.Reflection;

Assembly gerResAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("YourGerResourceAssembly.dll");
var resMgr = new ResourceManager("StringResources.Strings", gerResAssembly);
string gerString = resMgr.GetString("TheNameOfTheString");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it, with the [GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsb0cfet%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
calling the together with the specific [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you need.
for example:

```
using System.Resources;
using System.Reflection;

Assembly gerResAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("YourGerResourceAssembly.dll");
var resMgr = new ResourceManager("StringResources.Strings", gerResAssembly);

// for example german:
string strDE = resMgr.GetString("TheNameOfTheString",  new CultureInfo("de"));
// for example spanish
string strES = resMgr.GetString("TheNameOfTheString",  new CultureInfo("es"));
```

`