# Access an alternate resource file directly

Tags: c#, resources

I have a working language switch in my program. It uses a standard resource file and one extra copy for each language it supports. It works fine, both for the controls and for the strings in the code.

For one special case however, I would like to access the English resource file directly, no matter which langauge is currently chosen.

The reason is that, while I can translate named colors to say, German, for my popup menu, I can't use the non-English names for the `Color.FromName` method. So I want to display the translated name but still use the English name for the method call.

My resource files are called

```
DrawCtl_strings.resx
DrawCtl_strings.en.resx
DrawCtl_strings.de.resx
```

I tried:

```
DrawCtl_strings.en.mnRed;
```

but it doesn't compile..

Is there a (simple) way to do that **without** actually switching the language?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774836/load-resources-for-other-language?rq=1) post but I wonder if there could be a simpler, more direct way..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around a lot, I doubt that I can get around using the `ResourceManager`, after all.

So this works for me, creating two Dictionaries, one always English, the other the `CurrentUICulture`:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Knips.DrawCtl_strings", 
                            typeof(Knips.DrawCtl_strings).Assembly);

CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en");
ResourceSet resourceSet = rm.GetResourceSet(culture, true, true);

var englishResDict = resourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .ToDictionary(r => r.Key.ToString(), r => r.Value.ToString());

resourceSet = rm.GetResourceSet(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, true, true);

var currentResDict = resourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
    .ToDictionary(r => r.Key.ToString(), r => r.Value.ToString());
```

I then combine them to create my color dictionary (`Dictionary<string, string> ColorDict`):

```
foreach (var resEn in englishResDict.Keys)
     if (resEn.StartsWith("col_"))
         ColorDict.Add(englishResDict[resEn], currentResDict[resEn]);
```

I'm still relying on a naming convention, but at least it's one I can control..
(And of course it's up to me to guarantee the values' uniqueness.)

Sigh, I had hoped to get it right **and** save a few lines of code..